# LibreOffice: how to display several opened windows as a grid on the computer's screen?

Tags: windows, libreoffice

Basically that. OS: MACOS.
I need to compare several documents visually and wondered whether this option exists, or whether there is third-party software to meet this goal. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Your question is off-topic if you ask for recommendations or non-programming stuff. Do you mean a macro that arranges windows instead? What did you research in the documentation reveal? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: You didn't specify what operating system you want to do this trick on. In Windows 7, this was done using the Task Manager: (minimize all open windows with **Win+D** if necessary), open Task Manager **Ctrl+Shift+Esc**, in the first tab, select those windows that you want to align, choose from the menu  Windows-Horizontal (or Vertically).

Comment: In later versions of Windows, Microsoft has changed [**the way application windows are repositioned**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/snap-your-windows-885a9b1e-a983-a3b1-16cd-c531795e6241#:~:text=to%20find%20it.-,Snap%20layouts,-To%20optimize%20your). In any case, the arrangement of windows on the monitor screen is the task of the operating system, not the office suite.

Comment: It's in Mac. Thanks.